# How to change visible property of UI object from background task? javafx

Tags: javafx

I want to make a background task that check internet connection every few moments, if there will be no connection in the corner of main window should pop out a pane with error and disappear after few seconds. My idea is to change a visible property of this pane but i don't know how to do it

if there is a better way to do it please let me know

Comment: What have you tried?  What is working, what is not working?  Please post your code here so you can be assisted.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can have a regular Thread running in the background.  The Thread can have a reference to a JavaFX Node that represents your error.  If the thread detects an error it can then set the visibility.

Below is working rudimentary code that does just that.  The code shows that from a background Thread, you can in fact control JavaFX objects.

```
StackPane root = new StackPane();
double width = 300;
double height = 300;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, width, height);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    configure();
}

private void configure() {
    Label error = new Label("Error connecting");
    error.setFont(Font.font(20));
    error.setPrefWidth(width);
    error.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_RIGHT);
    root.getChildren().add(error);
    error.setVisible(false);
    //
    Timeline disableVisibility = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(
                    Duration.seconds(2), 
                    new KeyValue(error.visibleProperty(), false)
            )
    );

    //
    new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
                error.setVisible(true);
                disableVisibility.playFromStart();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }).start();

}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```